# Why is Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize() not late-binding?

Tags: java, late-binding, spliterator

I read up on spliterators today and implemented one using `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), Spliterator.NONNULL)`.  According to `spliteratorUnknownSize()`'s documentation

> The [resulting] spliterator is not late-binding

Being new to spliterators I am wondering why that is the case.  If I ensure `iterator()` to be late-binding, the resulting spliterator should also be, no?  `spliteratorUnknownSize()` is merely creating an `IteratorSpliterator` which does not bind to the element source yet.

I.e., I would love to understand why the resulting spliterator is not late-binding.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#binding):

> "A `Spliterator` that does not report `IMMUTABLE` or `CONCURRENT` is expected to have a documented policy concerning: when the `Spliterator` binds to the element source; and detection of structural interference of the element source detected after binding. A late-binding `Spliterator` binds to the source of elements at the point of first traversal, first split, or first query for estimated size, rather than at the time the `Spliterator` is created. A `Spliterator` that is not late-binding binds to the source of elements at the point of construction or first invocation of any method. Modifications made to the source prior to binding are reflected when the `Spliterator` is traversed. After binding a `Spliterator` should, on a best-effort basis, throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if structural interference is detected. ..."

So if you parse that carefully, *late-binding* versus *non-late-binding* is really about when detection of structural interference kicks in.

A `Spliterator` wrapping an *arbitrary* iterator cannot guarantee to detect structural interference.  It depends on how the `Iterator` is implemented.  And even for `Iterators` that do detect (or mitigate) structural interference, the `Spliterator` cannot make any guarantees about when the detection starts; i.e. when the "binding" occurs.

In short, it cannot guarantee true *late-binding* semantics.

---

> If I ensure `iterator()` to be late-binding, the resulting `Spliterator` should also be, no?

The javadocs don't guarantee that.

In practice: it probably should be, though it depends on the implementation of  `Spliterators`.  But making such a statement in the javadocs may constrain the implementation of *future* versions of the `Spliterators` class and its nested classes in ways that are harmful.

---

You may disagree with my analysis.  However the authors of the javadocs have clearly and deliberately stated that these `Spliterators` are not late bound.  If you think they are wrong about that, raise a Bug Report against the javadocs.